# Select rows not in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.value
FROM a LEFT JOIN b 
    ON a.value = b.value 
      AND (b.field IS NULL OR b.field != 'my_string');

SELECT a.value
FROM a
WHERE a.value NOT IN
    (SELECT value 
     FROM b
     WHERE b.field = 'my_string');
```

From what I've read, doing a LEFT JOIN is faster.  But I've also read that DISTINCT is code smell for inefficient query.  How do I go about determining which query performs better in a worst case scenario?

EDIT: sorry, id is not a primary key, it's just another field.  I'll replace it with value.

EDIT2: Looks like everybody's hung up on my first query.  Let's say it looks like this instead.  Isn't the logic the same?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.value
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.value = b.value 
WHERE (b.field IS NULL OR b.field != 'my_string');
```

EDIT3: Sample fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/500ea/1

EDIT4: Accepted answer.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/500ea/8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first join is non-sensical.  It returns all `a.id` values in `a`.  Remember, `left join` keeps all rows in the first table and matching rows in the second.  I think you intend:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b 
     ON a.id = b.id AND b.field = 'my_string'
WHERE b.field IS NULL;
```

The `distinct` should be unnecessary, assuming that `a.id` is, well, a unique id.

An alternative is to use `not exists`:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.id = b.id AND b.field = 'my_string');
```

For performance, create an index on `b(id, field)`.

Comment: ninjaed while writing same reply +1

Answer (score 0):

In general, the `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` is more inneficient than the `LEFT JOIN`, because the `SELECT` in the `IN()` condition must be executed once *for every row* in order to perform the filter. For small datasets, that's not a problem, but for large data sets, that can be <strike>quite a big headache</strike> quite inefficient.